# Fast non-linear system resolution (polynoms of degree 3)

Tags: polynomials, nonlinear-system

I have a nonlinear system of 3 equations with 27 constants and 3 unknowns `x, y, z`

```
K1 = x*(uX1*x^2+vX1*x+wX1) + y*(uX2*y^2+vX2*y+wX2) + z*(uX3*z^2+vX3*z+wX3)
K2 = x*(uY1*x^2+vY1*x+wY1) + y*(uY2*y^2+vY2*y+wY2) + z*(uY3*z^2+vY3*z+wY3)
K3 = x*(uZ1*x^2+vZ1*x+wZ1) + y*(uZ2*y^2+vZ2*y+wZ2) + z*(uZ3*z^2+vZ3*z+wZ3)
```

The equations are polynoms of degree 3 and only real and positive solutions for `x, y, z` are of interest for me.
Is there any method/algorithm that resolves either this system fastly (for real-time applications), either finds exact solutions?

Comment: You could take a generic system only containing cubic and constant terms, with coefficients close to the given ones, and then follow its 27 roots via a homotopy to the roots of the given system. With general coefficients there should be no shortcuts.

Comment: It is the intersection of 3 surfaces in $\mathbb{R^3}$...